# Jquery click event is not fired every time on all LI element of UL tag

Tags: jquery, click

Hi,

I have created drop down.A div tag contains ul which has list items.Whenever user clicks on the li element,that value has to be updated in the input box.The problem is click event is not fired on some of li elements.In first case, I put 3 LI elements,out of these only top two elements firing event but no last one.In second case, I changed LI elements to 5.Now only first 3 elements firing but not last 2.
Out f 8 elements 5 elements firing,but not last 3 elements. I am really confused with this behavior. What could be the wrong in my code..[Here is the link](http://jsfiddle.net/6Kd67/2/) .Can you please help me....

Comment: Update your fiddle, with only the relevant part of the problem? All other logic are distracting the main problem (At least for me)

Comment: Hi Starx, Thanks for your reply. I cannot precise since all that script is needed to run that drop down.Can you please check it and solve the issue..I am new to Jquery. If you dont mind pls try to solve..Looking forward for your reply.

Comment: I would love to help you, but I am way to much confused with the code, as you sure, every code is necessary for the effect to be reproduced?

Comment: Yes Starx, entire code is specific to drop down.Since I am new to jquery, my coding style is like that.That y I put comments too. If you can you may precise code..Thanks.

Comment: I found the problem, it was different event overlapping with each other. Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for your help and valuable time..Codef0rmer also found that.I have commented regarding the use of blur below his answer.Can you plz check it once..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line in your code causing a problem: (I do not think it is needed as you have `$(html).click()` event too)

```
$('.irmNDrdnInput').blur(function(){
    drndValId = 'drdn-val-'+$(this).attr('id').split('-')[2];
    $('#'+drdnValId).slideUp(300);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Kd67/5/

For tab-press, you can track the keyCode inside `$('.irmNDrdnInput').keydown()` event :

```
if (event.keyCode === 9) {
    $('.irmNDrdnVal').slideUp(300);
    return false;            
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6Kd67/7/

Comment: Oh thanks,Here what my intention is, My page may contain more than one drodown. So when ever use moves out of the dropdown using tab the dropdown value list must be closed..So can I achieve that blur without that event.By the way,I have to get no of li elements of opened value list.I tried like $('#'+drdnValId+'ul li').length;,but  its giving 0.Is there any way to get them...Thanks once again for ur reply...

Comment: Why is it causing a problem though?

Comment: @RamaRaoM: Where did you put that .length line into your code? Check whether you are getting any value in `drdnValId` variable.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ramstheroyal/6Kd67/8/..here is my update..I m getting drdnValId. I put those lines in $('.irmNDrdnInputBox').click() event.

Comment: I think previous link is not working..link is http://jsfiddle.net/ramstheroyal/6Kd67/8/

Comment: @RamaRaoM: put that line into the callback of slideDown(). 
$('#'+drdnValId).slideDown(300, function () {
   console.log($(this).find('ul > li').length);
});

More info : http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time and help.It working fine,But I didnt get what was the wrong with the previous statement which gives 0

Comment: @RamaRaoM: Because sliddown() shows the dropdown after a specific interval so your code executes before the actual dropdown has shown. you may get correct length if you use .show() instead of .slidDown().

Comment: But even if I write $('#'+drdnValId+'ul li').length inside callback function,its giving 0.Only $(this).find('ul > li').length) statement is giving correct result.what might be the reason?

Comment: @RamaRaoM: missing space before `ul` - has to be $('#'+drdnValId+' ul li').length.

Comment: Thats grt! I think you are master in Jquery ....Thanks a lot.Nice talking to you...

Answer (score 3):

Why are over complicating this effect? **Keep it Short and Simple (KISS)**

I created a simple demo for a previously asked question, check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/a6NJk/2/).

Another [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/a6NJk/3/) with slide in effect.

---

### Update

Your blur function is creating problem, since more than one event is being triggered at the same time, specially the `$('html').click()`, the effect is overlapping. Add a slight delay to get **everything working**

```
/*Close value popup of the element which has lost focus*/
$('.irmNDrdnInput').blur(function(){
    drndValId = 'drdn-val-'+$(this).attr('id').split('-')[2];
    $('#'+drdnValId).delay(100).slideUp(300);
});
```

#### [Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6Kd67/2/)

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Walkerneo, It does with an alternative.

Comment: @Walkerneo, I updated with answer to the question as well. Hope you like it?

Comment: Yeah, do yo know why the blur event is causing trouble? Do you think it's a jQuery bug?

Comment: @Walkerneo, Blur event is overlapping to other events? Its not a jQuery bug, its a usability bug